# Is there an alternative to ExitThread() that invokes local objects' destructors?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I've always assumed that using objects with automatic storage, like vectors, was pretty much safe from memory leaks, because they are *guaranteed* to be destroyed when they go out of scope.

However, very recently I learned that this is not the case if for some reason you need to terminate a thread execution by calling ExitThread(). I admit that my knowledge of C++ is thin, but I find somewhat baffling that the destructor is not called when you do this. Why is that? Don't they go out scope in this case?

Now to the practical question: is there an alternative function that will destroy local objects with automatic storage before exiting a thread? Or do I really have to resort to calling destructors explicitly or redesigning my code to avoid having to exit threads in this way?

Comment: The best way to exit a thread is _gracefully_, usually by returning from the function that was specified in the "begin thread" call (which differs depending on platform and library in use)

Comment: The `throw` keyword jumps to mind.  Catch it at the end of the thread function.

Comment: exactly, wrap the entire thread function in a try...catch and throw your custom-made exception

Comment: @HansPassant, interesting suggestion, I'll have to read a bit more on that to get the implementation right, but it definitely looks like the easiest way to achieve what I want without changing the code too much. Thanks for pointing that out!